# Symlinking gvimrc file?

Tags: symlink, macvim, vim

I wanted to keep all files related to vim in one folder under my $HOME directory, more specifically my gvimrc file.  I've moved the original .gvimrc file to $HOME/vim/.gvimrc and created a symlink under my $HOME directory.  However, when I run source %, simple functions do not run until I exit and restart the session.  For example:

```
function! EchoSomething()
  if &bg == dark
    echo "bg is dark"
  else
    echo "bg is light"
  endif
endfunction
```

This should echo the results on the cmdline, but it show nothing when I source my .gvimrc file.

Comment: Do you use Vim 7.4 or another version? Why `$HOME/vim` and not `$HOME/.vim`?

Comment: That snippet you've posted just defines the function; what's missing is the function _invocation_ with `:call`?!

Comment: I know how to :call the function. However When I do, there is no output on the cmdline.

Comment: @romainl it's vim 7.4, and it is in $HOME/.vim (forgot to add ".").  I have reason to believe that it is because I'm using gui version.  The script above seems to work in the terminal just fine before actually starting the editor.

Comment: Why should that work in the terminal? There, a `.gvimrc` isn't even invoked?! Your sketchy information makes it hard to troubleshoot. Also, please try setting a marker variable instead of `:echo`; there's less risk of overlooking it, and you don't actually want to echo during startup, do you?

Comment: Rename `$HOME/.vim/.gvimrc` to `$HOME/.vim/gvimrc` and remove your symlink. Also, `.gvimrc` is for GUI Vim.

Comment: @IngoKarkat No This is just a random example script.  I just was just using it as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred alternative to a symlink is to add a `source` directive to an otherwise empty file at `$HOME/.gvimrc`

So, if you have another `.gvimrc` at `/path/to/it/`, instead of creating a symlink, create an empty file at `$HOME/.gvimrc` and add the line:

```
source /path/to/it/.gvimrc
```

Comment: Does this address the problem? A symlink should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. `gvimrc` (with or without a dot and wherever it is located) is *not* sourced when you use vim in a terminal.
2. Since 7.4, CLI Vim and GUI Vim look for the classical `$HOME/.vimrc` *and* `$HOME/.vim/vimrc` and GUI Vim also looks look for the classical `$HOME/.gvimrc` *and* `$HOME/.vim/gvimrc`.

   So you can safely drop your symlinks and just rename `$HOME/.vim/.gvimrc` to `$HOME/.vim/gvimrc`.